# Jsonpath for array of objects with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jsonpath

I am trying to write a jsonpath for following object:

```
{
    "ParentArray": [
        {
            "ChildArray": [
                {
                    "ChildArrayObjectKey": "ChildArrayObjectValue1"
                },
                {
                    "ChildArrayObjectKey": "ChildArrayObjectValue2"
                }
            ]    
        },
        {
             "ChildArray": [
                {
                    "ChildArrayObjectKey": "ChildArrayObjectValue3"
                },
                {
                    "ChildArrayObjectKey": "ChildArrayObjectValue4"
                }
            ]  
        }  
    ]
}
```

Which would extract the object from the ParentArray. I am looking for an object which contains a value 'ChildArrayObjectValue3' in its ChildArray. The solution I think should work is:

```
$.ParentArray[?(@.ChildArray[?(@.ChildArrayObjectKey === 'ChildArrayObjectValue3')])]
```

But unfortunately it does not provide any results. What I would like to extract is:

```
{
    "ChildArray": [
        {
            "ChildArrayObjectKey": "ChildArrayObjectValue3"
        },
        {
            "ChildArrayObjectKey": "ChildArrayObjectValue4"
        }
    ]  
}
```

Comment: Did u get the solution

Comment: Unfortunately in the end I just did it in my code using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :   $.ParentArray..*[?(@.ChildArrayObjectKey == 'ChildArrayObjectValue3')]

Comment: Thx for the solution, but unfortunately it does not get what I need. Your expression gets the object from the ChildArray array, but what I need is no extract the object from the ParentArray, based on its values in ChildArray.

Comment: I edited the question with an example what exactly do I expect